# Syntax error in for loop Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.4

As an absolute beginner, I'd appreciate some help as to why the last "print" ( the  *print("Good bye!")* statement) comes up as "syntax error" I'm using Python 3.4 but am working through a 2... tutorial.

```
fruits = ['banana', 'apple',  'mango'] #Create list
for fruit in fruits:        
   print ('Current fruit :', fruit)

print ("Good bye!")
```

If I simply enter a blank line and do not indent it works, is this my error or a change in the syntax for 3.4?

Comment: Full traceback where?

Comment: Your code as I copied it into my interpreter runs fine with no errors.

Comment: Thank you both, I don't quite understand Ignacio's comment, however following Player72's comment I realized that perhaps trying the code directly in the shell could be the problem. Having written and saved the code as test.py, all went well. Obviously a beginner's error, so thank you again.